# How to make an object raise a "PropertyChanged" or execute a method on parent when its nested property changed?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have a model, and I don't want it implement INotifyPropertyChanged:

```
public class PeopleModel
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string company { get; set; }
}
```

And now I have a ViewModel:

```
public class DetailViewModel : CustomViewModelBase
{
    private PeopleModel _person;
    public PeopleModel person
    {
        get
        {
            return _person;
        }

        set
        {
            _person=value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
    public ICommand customOnUpdateCommand { get; set; }
}
```

Now, using WPF and only using XAML, I bind a textbox content to the name (The whole window is already bind to the ViewModel):

```
<StackPanel
    DataContext="{Binding Path=person}">
    <DockPanel>
        <Label Content="name" Target="{Binding ElementName=person_TextBox}" />
        <TextBox x:Name="person_TextBox"
                            Text="{Binding Path=name, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">

        </TextBox>
    </DockPanel>
</StackPanel>
```

Now, I want to do the following: when I change the name property in this person object, the person object should raise a "PropertyChanged" in the ViewModel. Or alternative, execute a custom command, or execute a method(which would be much better).

I already tried data triggers, System.Windows.Interactivity, or using RelativeSource, but they don't work, maybe I didn't use them correctly.

How do I achieve this correctly?

Note: I already confirmed that when the textbox changes, the name in the object will change correctly. So the binding process is correct.

Comment: You could give the child model a `NameChanged` event that it raises when its `Name` property changes. The parent viewmodel could handle that and raise `PropertyChanged`. I don't know if you can raise `PropertyChanged("PropertyName.ChildPropertyName")` and have it work. The usual way to do this is to wrap the model in a child viewmodel that implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

Comment: I can't see any point in reinventing the wheel here. You don't want change notifications, but you need change notifications, so you invent a new change notification mechanism which differs from the old one only in that it hasn't been debugged and tested yet (also it's probably not as well designed, because the guys who designed XAML were smarter than you and me and had more time, and you'll need to kludge something to make it work with existing controls which were designed for the OOTB notifications). The payoff on this is not clear to me.

Comment: If you're binding to it in the UI, and you want changes to show up automatically via a binding, then it puts the INotifyPropertyChanged on the model or else it gets the hose again.